# Make a click event based on a control's name value property

Tags: controls, screen, testcomplete

I'm using TestComplete for the automation of QA process.

TestComplete detects click events based on the postion of the mouse on the screen. But when I run the same test on a different machine (a larger/smaller screen) the mouse button won't click on the correct position.

Therefore I want to know is there a method which I can search a control based on its name (i.e. name of a button) and then run a script to click on that particular word (or position).

Any help is appreciated :)

**Additional Details**

This is a sample script generated by TestComplete for clicking the search button on a web page.

```
Sub Test6()
  'Opens the specified URL in a running instance of the specified browser.
  Call Browsers.Item(btIExplorer).Navigate("http://www.simplyrecipes.com/search/?cx=003084314295129404805%3Ai2-mkfc4cai&cof=FORID%3A11&q=&sa.x=48&sa.y=16")
  'Clicks at point (173, 10) of the 'textboxQ' object.
  Call Aliases.browser.pageHttpWwwSimplyrecipesComSearc.panelPage.headerMasthead.group.panelSiteSearch.formSearchbox0030843142951294048.textboxQ.Click(173, 10)
  'Sets the text 'asd' in the 'textboxQ' text editor.
  Call Aliases.browser.pageHttpWwwSimplyrecipesComSearc.panelPage.headerMasthead.group.panelSiteSearch.formSearchbox0030843142951294048.textboxQ.SetText("asd")
  'Clicks at point (57, 12) of the 'imagebuttonSa' object.
  Call Aliases.browser.pageHttpWwwSimplyrecipesComSearc.panelPage.headerMasthead.group.panelSiteSearch.formSearchbox0030843142951294048.imagebuttonSa.Click(57, 12)
End Sub
```

Here is the button click event captured in the RecordTest window

[image]

**What I want to know is, is there a way I can specify the control name (i.e 'Search' or 'imagebuttonSa'), so the TestComplete will search for the name in the given GUI and then once it's found, make a click event on the word**.

I'm using Windows 7 64bit OS, TestComplete 9 trial version and VBScript as the scripting language.

Comment: Actully, TestComplete always clicks a specific object/control when it is possible. Situations when TestComplete cannot locate an object and uses screen coordinates (actually, these coordinates are related to the top-level window of an application) are very rare. You need to provide more information on your situation: in which programming language your application is written, which OS you use, which exactly version of TestComplete you have. Also, it would be perfect if you post here the problematic script that performs a click by coordinates.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have edited my post with the new details.

Answer (score 1):

```
Whenever I have a problem with not finding an object with TC I use one of this functions or a combination of them.

In case you have the table object (parent of the cell you want to click):
function clickCellByText(text,tablePath)
{   
  var table = tablePath;
  if (!table.Exists)
  {
    Log.Error("A table with the following text cannot be found: " + table);
  }
  clickCell1(table, "*Cell*", "*Cell*");

  function clickCell1(table, idText, linkText)
  {
    var propArray = new Array("innerText", "ObjectType");
    var valArray = new Array(text,"Cell*");
    var idCell = table.FindChild(propArray, valArray, 20000);
    if (idCell.Exists)
    { 
      // Row found, find the link in the same row      
      idCell.Click(); 
    }
    else  
    {
      Log.Error("A cell with the following text cannot be found: " + text);
    }
  }
}

If you want to find the object or the parent of the object by any property:

function clickComponent(property,text)
{ 
   // Using the Find method 
   var myObj = Sys.Browser("iexplore").Page("*").NativeWebObject.Find(property,text);
   // Checks if the button exists 
   if (myObj.Exists)
   { 
      myObj.Click();     
   }
   else
     Log.Error("Can't find the object","");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify co-ordinate, it will click at the center of the object.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, TestComplete already works in your case with specific controls/objects: **textboxQ** and **imagebuttonSa**. These two names are given to objects by the [Name Mapping](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31493/) functionality and you are free to change them as you like.

As for the coordinates, these coordinates are related to the top left corner of the corresponding control (**textboxQ** or **imagebuttonSa**). If you want, you can remove the coordinates from the action parameters (e.g. ..**.imagebuttonSa.Click()**) and TestComplete will click the central point of the control.

In case you have any problems with playing back your tests and you cannot find out what the cause of these problems is, the best option for you will be [contacting](http://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=TestComplete) the SmartBear support team with detailed explanation of what happens. Send them your project with failed results logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing FindChild or Find with the Object Name Mapping where the button resides, with Properties like (Eg:ObjectType as Button and Button Caption with your required button caption), once the FindChild finds the button with above specified properties you can use that object to click on it:

`var button = ParentObj.FindChild(["ObjectType","Caption"],["Button","OK"],10);
if(button.Exists)
   button.Click()`